# Airflow - Python script doesn't execute when triggered

Tags: python, airflow

When I run the script it doesn't give me an error, however doesn't execute the task which is storing data from an API into MYSQL. The python script alone works fine.

```html
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 10, 15),
    'email': ['xxx@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    'end_date': datetime(2018, 10, 16),
}

#schedule_interval = "00 21 * * *"

schedule_interval = "* * * * *"

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=schedule_interval)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id= "RunPythonFile",
    bash_command= "python /Users/joaopimenta/documents/joaopython/twitterscripts/twitterMigrateFollowersSQLMultipleUsers.py",
    dag=dag
    )
```

Comment: I tried to use a pythonoperator to connect to the mysql database(which tbh doesn't seem necessary as it is done on the python script) but I also get the error "AirflowException: `python_callable` param must be callable"

Comment: Try put a space on the end of the command as:  `bash_command= "python /Users/joaopimenta/documents/joaopython/twitterscripts/twitterMigrateFollowersSQLMultipleUsers.py "`

Comment: Have you turned on the DAG in the GUI ?

Comment: Thanks Medhdeep I then noticed as you mentioned that I actually wanted to use airflow integrated with google cloud instead of locally. Turned on the UI and worked.